# TYPO3 Powermail | I don't get a mail after opening the confirmation link

Tags: typo3, powermail

I made a newsletter form with double opt-in in powermail.
There is no problem in the standard language (german).

When I fill it out on my english page I get a confirmation mail. 
Opening the link inside opens the confirmation page with no error but there is no mail afterwards.

The german and english form / configuration are identical.

I tried changing the sender and receiver values but nothing works.

I appreciate any help, advice or idea :)

TYPO3 Version 8.7.9
Powermail Version 6.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found this Extension which lead me to this github Issue:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/powermail_optin_fix/ 
https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/issues/213

**This Extension solved my problem!**

DI Michael Ganner wrote:

> When using OptIn on translated pages, the {powermail_all} marker in
>   the 2nd mail and 2nd confirmation page (after clicking the
>   confirmation-link) is empty. Reason: The answers of the mail are not
>   loaded in other languages than the default one.
>
> I "solved" the issue quick and dirty by adding the function
>   'gugler_addAnswers' to the FormController. This function is called in
>   FormController->optinConfirmAction():

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use config.sys_language_mode=strict. At the moment the situation is that powermail always stores mails with sys_language_uid=0. If you are using the strict mode for language fallback in general, powermail is not able to read the answers in a different language.

This behaviour isn't that easy to fix.

Comment: First of all thank you, I don't use language_mode in my setup, is there anything else I can try?